# define a global custom serializer for a genericc type in RavenDB

Tags: serialization, collections, f#, ravendb

Hi I'm trying to use RavenDB to serialize F# collections. This is no problem as long as you stick to the normal .net collections.
But I want to serialize F#-Lists, Tuples and maybe even Sets too.

Now as I understand it, I could decorate my F#-objects with some attributes to hook up some Json.net functionality (but I don't exactly know how too).

But I had hoped that there is a way to tell RavenDB to serialize - lets say all List<'a> in a certain way (to be exact - just handle them as a IEnumerable/Seq and use List.ofSeq in the constructor)

Is this possible and if yes can you explain exactly how?

Comment: Not an answer but note that you won't be able to store discriminated union. You might want to have a look at Robert Pickering's RavenDB serializer for Discriminated Union and how he does it.

Comment: where can I find it? (I think I saw this - you have to add some members to the algebraic-datatype in order to work - I guess it's the/a Id - field), but no this is sadly not the answer ... but thanks

Comment: I feel Ayende seemed to be improving things on support for F# and last time I tried to make Robert's add-in for discriminated union I couldn't make it work. Perhaps it's better to wait on built-in support in RavenDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the serializer by providing your own JsonConverter class, and registering that with the RavenDB serializer by providing a lambda for Conventions.CustomizeSerializer function.

Comment: thank you - are there any examples out there for this? I looked at the API documentation of Json.net - it's not bad at all but not very insightfull to this as well

Comment: there is one here: http://ravendb.net/faq/polymorphism . Will have a few more real examples later this week.